# Windows App and Asp.Net Encryption

Tags: asp.net, encryption, xamarin, uwp

I developed a asp.net webservice for a Xamarin app. I used a encryption class based on System.Security.Cryptography library

Now I want to develop the Universal App version, but I need to use Windows.Security.Cryptography library

I know they are different libraries, but there is a way to encrypt and decrypt in the same way? Or if not, there is any common library?

Thanks

Comment: most cryptography is an open standard use AES 128 or similar in both end it should work fine for both 

probably use bouncy castle it has a PCL library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto). With that you can use the same library for all the different project types. The library doesn't implement any cryptographic algorithms itself but relies on the platform specific implementations, so it's as safe to use as what you're doing now.

Comment: I will try and I tell you